# int rosu=Color.red.getRGB() from Java to C#

Tags: c#, java, .net, image, image-processing

I am converting by hand a code from Java to C#, and I don't know how to convert

`private static int rosu = Color.Red.getRGB;`

I get this error:

```
'System.Drawing.Color' does not contain a definition for 'getRGB' and no extension method 'getRGB' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Drawing.Color' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I use the declared `rosu` in this context:

```
       for (uy=0;uy<h;uy++)
            for (ux=0;ux<w;ux++)
                if(curba[uy][ux]==255)
                      curba[uy][ux]=rosu;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
private static int rosu = Color.Red.ToArgb();
```

The .Net `Color` class is basically just a wrapper around `int` anyway, so in your conversion you may want to instead change all your color variables from `int` to `Color`.

Comment: now I get this error: Cannot convert method group 'ToArgb' to non-delegate type 'int'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: Don't leave out the parentheses at the end of the line.

Comment: Be careful - the Java code seems to return RGB, while this gives you ARGB!

Comment: @Gabe: that shouldn't really matter, unless he's making use of the alpha channel in some way.

Comment: Since Red is 0x00FF0000 as RGB but 0xFFFF0000 as ARGB, it could make a difference.